# Shiny removeUI selector remove the parent div unexpectedly

Tags: jquery, r, shiny

I'm working on a Shiny app. I have problem with using both renderUI and removeUI the same time. I want to generate a selectInput ui containing integer or numeric columns (`input$sumcol`) if I choose "sum" aggregation function in `input$aggr` selectInput. Here's my code:

```
# elements in ui
selectInput("vars", "data to display:", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE, selected = NULL),
selectInput("aggr", "aggregation function:", choices = c("count", "sum"), selected = NULL),
uiOutput("sumcolcontrol")

#server

## create/delete #sumcoldiv  based on selection of input$aggr
observeEvent(input$aggr, {

  if(input$aggr == "sum") { 
    # create sumcol select UI
    output$sumcolcontrol <- renderUI({
      # add a div that contains input$sumcol, so it's easy to remove the div by id later
      tags$div(id = "sumcoldiv",selectInput("sumcol", "column to sum:", choices = dt$numcols, width = "50%"))
    })
  } else {
    # delete the div of id "#sumcoldiv"
    removeUI(selector = "div:has(>#sumcoldiv)")
  }
})
```

However, the above code only works successfully for the first time (the first time I choose "sum", the ui is generated successfully, and I can remove the ui by choosing "count"). However, I can't generate the ui again by choosing "sum" for `input$aggr`the second time and above. Inspecting the elements in browser, it seems the problem is with `removeUI` because the following div 
`<div id="sumcolcontrol" class="shiny-html-output shiny-bound-output"></div>` is gone after `removeUI` is called for the first time. Supposedly this shall only remove `<div id="sumcoldiv">`, I wonder what's wrong with my code here? I'm not familiar with jQuery selector, I read removeUI documentation and it seems to me my code is right. Please help!

Comment: `"div:has(>#sumcoldiv)"` it should delete the div which contain an element with id `sumcoldiv` if you need to just remove the div with id `sumcoldiv` you can use `div#sumcoldiv` ... I highly recommend to take a look at [CSS Selectors](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)  *This solution will help if selector is your problem* .. Additional information *(ID suppose to be unique don't use same id for more than one element)*

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Thanks, it works now!

Comment: You're welcome.. Have a great day :) ... I will post it as an answer to let anyone know the problem solved and may be that answer help another person in the future

Comment: She ought to accept the answer though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The :has() CSS pseudo-class represents an element if any of the
>   selectors, relative to the:scope of the given element, passed as
>   parameters, matches at least one element. The :has() pseudo-class
>   takes a selector list as an argument.

**Syntax**

```
:has(selector_list) { style properties }
```

**Examples**

The following selector matches only elements that contain an id `sumcoldiv` child and by using `>` it means a direct child:

```
'div:has(>#sumcoldiv)'
```

*Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has*

**So,** in your code

```
"div:has(>#sumcoldiv)"
```

it should remove the div which contain an element with id `sumcoldiv`

If you need to just remove the div with id `sumcoldiv` you can use

```
'div#sumcoldiv'
```

> I highly recommend to take a look at [CSS Selectors](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048) you will not find `:has` selector there but it will make you more familiar with selectors

***Additional information*** 
(ID suppose to be unique don't use same id for more than one element)